Can we know we exist without knowing what we are, or what existence is?
I saw this assertion online:

To say you know you exist necessarily means you understand what you are, what existence is, and what it means for something to exist

I was wondering if that is philosophically sound, surely we can claim we exist as a basic, non-inferential truth stemming from introspection of our own conscious states, right? Such a claim does not require knowing what we are, no?

I think this is an impossible question to answer, except by referring you to all the philosophers who have tried and failed to come up with convincing answers to similar questions. Personally, I don't feel any need to question who or what I am, but if you're going to do so you won't be the first.

Words have multiple meanings. This often makes sentences true with some meanings that are also false with other meanings. You can know what the symbol means (what idea it denotes)... and not know what the symbol means (all the physical properties of the referent of the idea denoted by the symbol)... or what the symbol means (the teleological purpose for the referent)... or what the symbol means (the consequences of the fact thus expressed)... or what the symbol means (how your use of the symbol will affect me).

Per exstentialism's existence precedes essence doctrine, this assertion could be strengthened much further as "To say you know you exist necessarily means you understand all essential things about you unconditionally..."

The quoted assertion seems stronger than what the title asks, and is likely false, see SEP, Understanding: "Knowledge, as now commonly conceived, can apparently be quite easy to get... understanding typically seems harder to acquire, and more of an epistemic accomplishment, than knowledge... the objects of understanding seem more structured and interconnected." What "knowing what" means in the OP is unclear, but if it means understanding then no, we do not need to be able to spell out every "what" about some X to just know X.

Yes; I submit myself as an example.

You are aware that this question has been at the back of people's minds like, forever, and was answered decisively and elegantly in 1637? It is impossible to ask this question without answering it implicitly! ;-)

Can someone know he has a glass of water in his hand without knowing that water is a compound of hydrogen and oxygen? Can someone know he is looking at the Morning Star without knowing that the Morning Star is the second planet in the Solar System and is the same as the Evening Star? Can someone know that you are angry without knowing what you are angry about and without experiencing your anger? Can someone know that a basketball player set a good pick even though he doesn't have the skill or training to set a good pick himself?
In order to know X is Y, you don't have to know everything there is to know about either X or Yness; you just need the ability to recognize an X and to recognize when something is Y. So, no, in order to say that I exist, I don't need a full metaphysical account of humankind or of existence.

Right, otherwise we would not be able to know anything.

I would argue that the third criterion ("[know] what it means for something to exist") is entirely justified, because that's just saying that you need to know the definitions of words you use in a sentence. You can't go around asserting things that have no known or understood definition. The first two are less defensible.

Medieval philosophy operates with the two different technical terms: existentia = existence and essentia = essence.
Accordingly, medieval philosophy could reply to your post: Yes, we know that we exist, but we do not necessarily know who we are.
Or: We know that God exists, but we do not necessarily know who he is.
"Essence" itself is a much older term, already used by Aristotle and named “ousia”.

OP: "Can we know we exist without knowing what we are, or what existence is?"
Yes, one can know intuitively that one exists, that the table exists, and indeed without ever even really thinking about what one's existence entails, its finitude. One could be carefree, or perhaps careless.
The term 'human being' basically just says Earthling: a being, qualified as human (earthly), so pretty vague.
As for what existence is, we can say we understand it as it applies to things, but in itself it is a conundrum.  Suppose we say things exist due to existence, or existence makes or allows for things to exist, then evidently existence cannot be a thing itself because then we would not be addressing the root of the existence of things. In this absolute sense it cannot even be a process because a process is a thing.
Furthermore if we try to define existence then we would start to say "existence is ... ", but this is circular and void because it would use what it is trying to define in its own definition.  This much is stated in Being & Time, ¶ 1. The Necessity for Explicitly Restating the Question of Being


First, it has been maintained that 'Being' is the 'most universal' concept: τὸ ὄν ἐστι καθόλου μάλιστα πάντων.i Illud quod
primo cadit sub apprehensione est ens, cuius intellectus includitur in
omnibus, quaecumque quis apprehendit. 'An understanding of Being is
already included in conceiving anything which one apprehends as an
entity.'1,ii But the 'universality' of 'Being' is not that
of a class or genus. The term 'Being' does not define that realm
of entities which is uppermost when these are Articulated conceptually
according to genus and species: οὔτε τὸ ὄν γένος.iii The
'universality' of Being 'transcends' any universality of genus. . .
.

It has been maintained secondly that the concept of 'Being' is [4] indefinable. This is deduced from its supreme
universality,iv and rightly so, if definitio fit per genus
proximum et differentiam specificam [Wikipedia]. 'Being' cannot indeed be
conceived as an entity; enti non additur aliqua natura: nor can it
acquire such a character as to have the term "entity" applied to it.
"Being" cannot be derived from higher concepts by definition, nor can
it be presented through lower ones. But does this imply that 'Being'
no longer offers a problem? Not at all. We can infer only that 'Being'
cannot have the character of an entity.


i. (H. 3) Aristotle, Metaphysica B 4, 1001 a 21.
ii. (H. 3) Thomas Aquinas, Summa Theologica 111 Q.94 art.
2.
iii. (H. 3) Aristotle, Metaphysica B 3, 998 b 22.
iv. (H. 4) Cf. Pascal, Pensées et
Opuscules (ed.
Brunschvicg),6 Paris, 1912, p, 169, ‘On ne peut entreprendre de
définir l’être sans tomber dans cette absurdité: car on ne peut
définir un mot sans commencer par celui-ci, c’est, soit qu’on
l’exprime ou qu’on le sous-entende. Donc pour définir l’être, il
faudrait dire c’est, et ainsi employer le mot défini dans sa
définition.’

It has been argued that in simply discussing 'being' it can be comprehended as an entity. Heidegger addressed this by putting Being 'under erasure' to emphasise that we are trying to understand something, naming it without yet knowing what it is.

In Heidegger: The Question of Being & History (1964), p. 51–52, Jacques Derrida refers to the problem as a shortcoming of language that in all other cases can deal with the contingent existence of things. E.g. in saying "confusion is possible" confusion can be a thing that exists, but in saying "existence is problematic" can existence be a thing?

"the expression Sein is not only an infinitive but a verbal
substantive ... It consolidates [being] and makes it into something.
... Should we abandon a grammatical form that is so threatening for
the right thinking of being, a thinking that is neither a concept nor
a thinking of a being? ... What would happen if giving up on the
grammatical form of the verbal substantive in philosophical discourse,
we had to limit ourselves to the other forms? ... In that case, one
would say: being? — I know nothing about it. I do not know what that
means, primarily because I’ve never come across it and no one will
ever come across it. The pre-comprehension Heidegger talks about at
the beginning of Sein und Zeit is in this case merely an
incomprehension. I understand what being means only when being comes
to determine something or is determined by something, when I say I
am, and you are, and he or it is, and so on."

So the OP's assertion: "To say you know you exist necessarily means you understand what you are, what existence is, and what it means for something to exist" – precisely what existence is is far from straightforward.
As a basis for the positive sciences, which deal with things that exist, it is necessary to establish the problematic.

Ontological inquiry is indeed more primordial, as over
against the ontical3 inquiry of the positive sciences. But
it remains itself naïve and opaque if in its researches into the Being
of entities it fails to discuss the meaning of Being in general. And
even the ontological task of constructing a non-deductive genealogy of
the different possible ways of Being requires that we first come to an
understanding of 'what we really mean by this expression "Being"'.
The question of Being aims therefore at ascertaining the a priori
conditions not only for the possibility of the sciences which examine
entities as entities of such and such a type, and, in so doing,
already operate with an understanding of Being, but also for the
possibility of those ontologies themselves which are prior to the
ontical sciences and which provide their foundations.  (Being &
Time, H.11)

Even for a realist/materialist conception of being the scope is enormous, encompassing cosmology (origin of cyclical Big Bang?), the hard problem of consciousness, and the open potential for unknown psychical and physical possibilities. – Just to sketch some of the involvements.

Of course.  It is possible.  Advaita philosophy points towards this truth.  And that is its greatest significance.  If the word Advaita means non-dual, the word -- ‘we’ must be meaningless because the word – ‘we’ is for dual (or for many). Self realization is not a term just for understanding something like a difficult problem in maths, physics etc. Since it transcends time and is incomparable, it is the actual realization in all its sense.
Self-realization is incomparable because the inner Self, or Atman, is beyond comparison. It is said to be beyond all elements of nature, time, appearance, body, and mind. It is also said to be the Being of all, and to abide in its own fullness, peace, and ananda.
Of the transient there is no endurance, and of the eternal there is no cessation.
Since self realization is not a new thing or state to attain, in the absolute sense, words of Ramana Maharshi is the truth. --
There is no knowing or realising the Self.

If you think, then it's legitimate to infer that someone's thinking, right?

That doesn't seem to address the question being asked, of what is doing the thinking.

@keshlam The question doesn't address the question of who's doing the thinking, only whether we can infer our own existence from the fact that somebody is thinking. We can.

Depends on how one defines existence, but I will grant cogito ergo sum is pretty basic and hard to refute.

And the question does explicitly ask "what we are". CES doesn't answer that one.

@keshlam The question asks,"Can we know if we exist, if x...." However, we know we exist in any case, whether ix is true or false. Therefore we don't need to evaluate it.

@Miss_Understands What you say is true, but I am afraid it does not answer the question. The question is more about understanding the language, i.e. giving the sentence a useful semantic. AFAIU, this quoted sentence in the question is not really about ontology, but more about philosophy of language.

@rexkogitans > What you say is true,=== Everything I say is === but I am afraid it does not answer the question.  === It answers the question that was asked. You may want to restate the question.

This post was flagged for deletion for quality. Consider the rule that an answer should have a minimum of three sentences, and that one reference that supports your answer might help avoid being flagged. I hate to see your work deleted. If you haven't, make sure you read the help center. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

I don't have a need to shut you down. Just thought I'd offer you a route to self-improvement. How you receive that is on you. ; )
